# PlayFramework 2.0.1 asset versioning

Tags: playframework

I like the support of LESS css and Google Closure compiler for Play 2. Is there a way to add support for automatic versioning as well so that I don't have to worry about renaming files everytime a make a change.
How do other folks in the community handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a caching problem you are talking about. If it is a versionning problem you are talking about, this is the work of a [Version Control System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) like git or mercurial.

You will have this caching problem with every static resources.

**The problem**

In order to have web pages displayed quickly on the client side (and in order to have not so many requests for static contents on the server side) you will add Cache-Control and Etag directives in you HTTP responses. The browser will then get these static resources from its cache.

But if you change your logo.png (changing you firm logo for example), as this image is stored in the browser cache, the users won't see you new logo.

**Solutions**

I see two solutions for that:

- Play with the Etag and Cache-control directives to let the user request the new static resources every X days. I do that with a front-end server ([Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) for example) but you can also use play support for that (detailed [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Assets))
- Create a fake [query parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) which contains the resource version. For example you can have `http://www.mydomain.com/public/images/logo.png?v=1.2`. If you change the `v` parameter, the browser won't retrieve it from cache. On the server side the query parameter won't change anything and the served resource will be cached again.

I use the second solution with a configuration parameter in my application.conf appended to all static resources. This assumes that when you update a single resource, all the resources are reloaded again (generaly, when you change your images, you will also change your css and, why not, your js files...)

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on what you did for #2? Did you rename the files? Can we see what you put in the application.conf for this?

Comment: In application.conf: application.version=1.2. In your template : <img src="/public/images/logo.png?v=@(play.api.Play.application.getConfig("application.version").getOrElse("1.0"))" />. This is the idea, you can create your methods or implicit params to have it more easy to use.

Comment: As far as I've read, some proxy servers refuse to ever cache anything with a `?` in the URL. So you might consider moving the version part of the URL to the URL path instead, e.g.: `server/assets/<version>/logo.png`.

Comment: "generaly, when you change your images, you will also change your css and, why not, your js files", what? This is kitchen sink versioning, would be better to check modify time of assets and apply fingerprint accordingly. Of course that is more involved -- some progress on this front has been made here: "https://github.com/jroper/play-versioned-assets-example/blob/master/app/controllers/VersionedAssets.scala"

Comment: @KajMagnus You should consider to post your comment as a regular answer. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!